# Can't get rjs to work right, maybe issue with difference between link_to_remote and link_to with :remote => true

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, rjs, link-to, link-to-remote

I am having problems setting rjs up and I don't know the right way to code this for rails 2.3.14
Are they (link_to_remote and link_to with :remote > true) the same or do they reflect rails versions or are they in fact different?
I am using prototype, as required by my company (so jquery is not an option).

I also see that there is link_to_function so I am really not sure what the right approach is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to :remote => true` is a Rails 3 convention and doesn't work in Rails 2. Since you are using Rails 2.3 you'll want to use `link_to_remote` for ajax calls.

`link_to_function` is used for when you want some javascript to run when a link is clicked and not necessarily an ajax call to the server. Stuff like showing/hiding elements on a page.

Comment: Yes this was totally the right answer!  Now I am have to work on understanding url vs url_for and when to use which